# Software for building mosaics from irregular shapes

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing

Do you know any software that can build mosaics resembling original picture from collection of irregular shapes? Something doing what 'real' mosaic actually is.

Let's say source shapes are given in some pre-processed form, as same-scale png images with transparent background for instance.